# window.opener is useless after a redirect in the popup window (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, window

I'm building an app that involves authentication via third-party. To make the process not redirect the actual app I open a new window that then does the authentication and returns to main window after success.

This doesn't, however, go as well as planned. When the popup redirects to third-party and back, `window.opener` gets `null`. It's still possible to close the popup by `window.close()` but I also need to refresh the logged-in-area in the main window, like this:

```
window.opener.check_auth_status();
```

I really hope there is a way to fix this, e.g. binding a function to popup-close in the main window? Refreshing the whole page would be highly unnecessary.

One way is to [set an interval to main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140133/how-would-i-raise-an-event-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript-when-a-popup-window-is) checking if the popup is closed, but this seems so fiddly.

Comment: exactly that is working for me. I open a popup to twitter/facebook, after they redirect the popup back i call window.opener to refresh. Maybe your callback is different domain/port, because only works for the same page to access the opener that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few options that may or may not work in the latest versions of the browsers due to security updates

1) check that the window is closed from the opener - not fiddly and actually the safest

2) give the opener a name

```
window.name="myMainWindow";
```

and in popup (script from SAME domain) - should normally not open a new window or change content

```
var handle = window.open("","myMainWindow"); 
handle.check_auth_status();
```

3) use an iFrame in the popup and when you want to access the opener, use top.opener