# Windows.open - how do I handle when it's being closed?

Tags: javascript

By calling `window.open` I'm opening a new window with external website from my Sinatra application:

```
%a{:href=>"some_external_website.com", :target=>"blank", :onclick=>"popupWin = window.open(this.href, 'test', 'location,width=600,height=500,top=0'); popupWin.focus(); return false; window.open('')"}
```

I want to handle a moment when an user is closing a window. How can I do it? Of course, in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I raise an event (jQuery or vanilla Javascript) when a popup window is closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140133/how-would-i-raise-an-event-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript-when-a-popup-window-is)

Answer (score -1):

Add an [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) handler to the window. Using your current approach:

```
var popupWin = window.open(this.href, 'test', 'location,width=600,height=500,top=0');
popupWin.focus();
// add an onunload handler
popupWin.onunload = function () { ... };
return false;
window.open('') // this is dead code, unconditional return above...
```

Comment: It's not working, I don't know why. `%a{:href=>"test.com", :target=>"blank", :onclick=>"popupWin = window.open(this.href, 'test auth', 'location,width=600,height=500,top=0'); popupWin.focus(); popupWin.unload = function () { alert('it was closed!') }; return false;"}`

Comment: @AlanDert sorry, try `onunload` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work either, it shows alert as the window is opening.